# VB.NET dataset displaying database rows incorrectly

Tags: database, vb.net, dataset

I would say I'm new to VB but I have been using it for over a year although for mainly small tasks (mostly school related). Anyway my current project is for my A-Level task and I need to be able to add, update, delete and read from a database. My current code allows this to happen but after a new record is added to my database the dataset in VB displays the rows differently. I have 3 tables: "PlayerInfo", "PlayerSkill" and "PlayerAbilities". when a new record is added; the new "PlayerInfo" information becomes the first row in my dataset while the "PlayerSkill" and "PlayerAbilities" become the last row. This causes all of the information to be improperly matched up. I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem and if they know how to solve it.

This shows the working code to add to my database.

```
If inc <> -1 Then
        Dim cb1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da1)
        Dim cb2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da2)
        Dim cb3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da3)
        Dim dsNewRow1 As DataRow
        Dim dsNewRow2 As DataRow
        Dim dsNewRow3 As DataRow
        Try
            dsNewRow1 = ds1.Tables("Players").NewRow()
            dsNewRow1.Item("Forename") = Forename.Text()
            dsNewRow1.Item("Surname") = Surname.Text()
            ds1.Tables("Players").Rows.Add(dsNewRow1)
            da1.Update(ds1, "Players")

            dsNewRow3 = ds3.Tables("Players").NewRow()
            dsNewRow3.Item("Reactions") = Reactions.Text()
            dsNewRow3.Item("Strength") = Strength.Text()
            dsNewRow3.Item("Speed") = Speed.Text()
            dsNewRow3.Item("Stamina") = Stamina.Text()
            dsNewRow3.Item("Accuracy") = Accuracy.Text()
            dsNewRow3.Item("Coordination") = Coordination.Text()
            ds3.Tables("Players").Rows.Add(dsNewRow3)
            da3.Update(ds3, "Players")

            dsNewRow2 = ds2.Tables("Players").NewRow()
            dsNewRow2.Item("RegularShot") = RegularShot.Text()
            dsNewRow2.Item("ShortServe") = ShortServe.Text()
            dsNewRow2.Item("FlickServe") = FlickServe.Text()
            dsNewRow2.Item("Clear") = Clear.Text()
            dsNewRow2.Item("Smash") = Smash.Text()
            dsNewRow2.Item("DropShot") = DropShot.Text()
            ds2.Tables("Players").Rows.Add(dsNewRow2)
            da2.Update(ds2, "Players")

            MsgBox("New Record added to the Database")
            Commit.Enabled = False
            AddNew.Enabled = True
            Update.Enabled = True
            Delete.Enabled = True
        Catch
            MsgBox("Error")
            Me.Close()
        End Try
    End If
```

This shows the code that displays each of the dataset records inside different text boxes.

```
Try
        Forename.Text = ds1.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(1)
        Surname.Text = ds1.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(2)
        Speed.Text = ds3.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(3)
        Strength.Text = ds3.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(2)
        Reactions.Text = ds3.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(1)
        Stamina.Text = ds3.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(4)
        Coordination.Text = ds3.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(6)
        Accuracy.Text = ds3.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(5)
        ShortServe.Text = ds2.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(2)
        FlickServe.Text = ds2.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(3)
        Clear.Text = ds2.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(4)
        Smash.Text = ds2.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(5)
        DropShot.Text = ds2.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(6)
        RegularShot.Text = ds2.Tables("Players").Rows(inc).Item(1)
    Catch
        MsgBox("Error")
        Me.Close()
    End Try
```

Sadly I do not currently have enough "Rep" to upload a picture of the dataset.
Also sorry if this is not enough information, I'm not really used to using forums and such.

Comment: looks like you are adding data to the same table. You are talking about 3 tables!

Comment: @Kami he has 3 different datasets, each one with one table, all tables with the same name

Comment: Ok, you cannot have multiple tables with the same name in the DB. :)

Comment: @Kami Ok I have changed all of the table names to be unique to each table but the problem still persists. Any ideas?

Comment: @Deebs: Why don't you join the 3 tables in a query and pass the result to your datatset?

Comment: @Kami I tried that before but couldn't get it to work. For some reason the program didn't like the query no matter how I tried to lay it out. This is the only solution that has worked to me but is still giving me my current problem.

Comment: Can  you share your query?

Comment: @Kami I can't remember it exactly and have since removed the query from my code. If I remember correctly it was along the lines of: "INSERT INTO `PlayerInfo` (`Forename`, `Surname`) VALUES (GlobalVar.PlayerForename, GlobalVar.PlayerSurname) WHERE [Player#] = GlobalVar.PlayerNum"
Player# is the ID of the primary key in the database and message boxes confirmed all of the variables had values. I had a similar query for each of the other tables. I have a feeling this isn't what you mean though.

Comment: @Deebs17, I actually meant your select statement.

Comment: @Kami SELECT Forename, Surname FROM PlayerInfo WHERE [Player#] = GlobalVar.PlayerNum
Again, similar queries for the other tables.

Comment: wihtout seeing more of your code it is difficult see through the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this counts as an answer as I still don't know what caused the problem in the first case. Anyway I've got my code doing what I wanted by editing the SQL statements to display the rows in order of the primary key. ORDER BY [Player#]. I did have to change the name to just "Player" because the "CommandBuilder" doesn't like special characters.